# gl.h included before glew.h?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I've been getting this error "error C1189: gl.h included before glew.h" though my includes seem to be in the right order.

I also get a 9 warnings saying "warning C4005: 'APIENTRY' : macro redefinition"

I think it may be note worthy to say that I didn't get error before switching to GLFW 3, previously I was using GLFW 2. Below is the include at the top of my "Core.h".

```
//External Libraries

#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


//Default Libraries
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error msg, and also the snippet of the #includes in this C file ?

Comment: if you change to glfw2.h it works?
Is it possible something like a precompiled header is doing an include? Maybe stdafx.h ?

Comment: Ok their aren't any includes in the cpp files except including this header. I was thinking that it might be one of other classes including glew but that doesn't so far seem the case. And another note would be that I get the error right when it compiles the glew header it doesn't seem to get to glfw's include. And the error that I posted above is the only error except for this warningwarning "C4005: 'APIENTRY' : macro redefinition "

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out what seems to have happened is that I had a circular dependency which was also including glfw twice.